# Firebird 2.5x CAST Date from String

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to select all records that have the same date as today.

The actualy field that holds the date has this format

```
31.05.18-31.06.18
```

but can be also be like this

```
31.05.2018-31.06.2018
```

or can even hold other data or no data

So I need a robust method to choose the date after the "-" and compare it to 'now' and if there is no "-02.06.2018" (today) then it should not select the record.

I got so far:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  FELD1 IS NOT NULL AND
  NOT FELD1 = '' AND
  FELD1 LIKE '%-%' AND
  CAST(iif(Position('-' IN FELD1) IS NULL OR Position('-' IN FELD1) = 0, '',     Right(FELD1, Position('-' IN FELD1) - 1)) AS DATE),
  Position('-' IN FELD1) < 'NOW'
```

Comment: I got a little bit further and changed my example. But is this really robust?

Comment: Change your data model. This is not robust at all. The only real solution is to use two separate columns of type DATE. Also, you really should not be using `'NOW'` as it is really easy to get wrong results if a conversion ends up as a string type instead of a date or timestamp, please use `CURRENT_DATE`. As it stands, you are not really asking a question, please clarify what you are really asking.

Comment: Thanx. I cannot change the data, it is like I get it. My question is how to splitt the data of the field the best way to retriev the second date of it.