# Validate date in Textfield

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a textfield where two dates are stored, separated by "-" .

```
10.11.2022-15.11.2022
```

I select the first part as date

```
SELECT
  ART.ID,
  CAST(RIGHT(ART.FIELD1, POSITION('-' IN ART.FIELD1) - 1) AS DATE)
FROM
  PRODUCTS ART
```

Problem is if the textfield does not contain the right format, I get an error.

```
 1h32i2o-15.11.2022
```

So, I need a function in the WHERE clause which validates if the first part contains data that can be cast as DATE.

Comment: You should validate this *before* it is stored in the database, in fact, you should have two separate fields for this in your database. In any case, this is far easier solved in Firebird 3.0 and higher than in Firebird 2.5. In Firebird 2.5 you'll need to write (or find) a native UDF that does this for you, in Firebird 3.0 you would be able to write a PSQL function. Alternatively, solve this in your presentation layer instead of trying to do this in the query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebird SQL test if string contains DATE in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976473/firebird-sql-test-if-string-contains-date-in-where-clause)

Comment: Also: [Firebird 2.5x CAST Date from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50661153/firebird-2-5x-cast-date-from-string)

Comment: Another duplicate: [Cast as Int only when character is a number on Firebird 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288228/cast-as-int-only-when-character-is-a-number-on-firebird-2-5)

Comment: Violation of 1NF always fire back...

Comment: @Mark Rotteweel - This is not my DB I cant change anything, I just can read out.

Comment: The first duplicate I linked is basically the same question you asked 4 years ago, you'll just need to modify the pattern a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I thought there would be a special function like in MS SQL "IsDate()" or alike.